# Reading a Request Parameter as a List in Groovy and SoapUI

Tags: rest, groovy, get, soapui

I'm using SoapUI 4.6.4 with the MockService "feature".

This service will receive a request like:

```
code=abcdef&code=123456&code=78910
```

In the "OnRequest Script" tab in SoapUI  (which accept Groovy code), I'd like to retreive all the "codes" from the query string parameters and loop trough the list (to do some operations on each code and alter write the response)

Here's my code so far:

```
def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse

httpResponse.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8")
// Get all "codes" from request as a list
// loop trought list of codes one by one

def generatedResponse = "";
httpResponse.writer << "{\"codes\": [" + generatedResponse + "]}"

httpResponse.status = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest in my opinion:

```
def arrayOfCodes = "code=abcdef&code=123456&code=78910".replace("code=", "").split("&")
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you get the query string code=abcdef&code=123456&code=78910 from the request?